# Python class returning old value of attribute

Tags: python, class, oop, attributes

I have a main class, a second class that handles getting a sudoku grid (2D array), and a third class that solves the puzzle and is supposed to return a completed puzzle. When I run the program, the solve method works fine and prints out the solved puzzle. However, when I call `SudokuSolver.get_grid()` from another class, the original, unsolved grid that was passed into `SudokuSolver` is being returned. Also, when I tried to return `self.grid` from the `solve()` method, it always returns `[[None]]`.

Here is my solver class:

```
import numpy as np


class SudokuSolver:

    def __init__(self, in_grid):
        self.grid = in_grid

    def get_grid(self):
        return self.grid

    def solve(self):

        for y in range(9):
            for x in range(9):
                if self.grid[y][x] == 0:
                    for n in range(1, 10):
                        if self.possible(y, x, n):
                            self.grid[y][x] = n
                            self.solve()
                            self.grid[y][x] = 0
                    return
        print('Solved')
        print(np.matrix(self.grid))

    def possible(self, y, x, n):

        for i in range(0, 9):
            if self.grid[y][i] == n:
                return False
        for i in range(0, 9):
            if self.grid[i][x] == n:
                return False

        x0 = (x//3) * 3
        y0 = (y//3) * 3

        for i in range(0, 3):
            for j in range(0, 3):
                if self.grid[y0 + i][x0 + j] == n:
                    return False

        return True
```

Second Class:

```
solver = SudokuSolver(self.get_grid())
solver.solve()
completed = solver.get_grid()
print('Completed')
print(np.matrix(completed))
```

Why is `SudokuSolver` returning the old grid value that was passed in, and not the completed one printed at the end of the `solve()` method?

Comment: Could you post (or link to) an example of the format it expects for its grid? That would make it easier to reproduce and test the issue. (Also, I don't think you need the `get_grid` method—in Python, it's usually good form to avoid getters unless they actually do something. Simply access `solver.grid` directly.)

Comment: `SudokuSolver(self.get_grid())` produces a NameError.

Comment: If either of the answers solved your problem, please consider upvoting and accepting. Otherwise, you can comment with questions or issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```py
self.grid[y][x] = 0
```

is getting called repeatedly *after* the solution is complete. To verify, put any `print` statement immediately before or after it. You'll see that its output will appear both before and after your "Solved" output.

I am not well-versed in Sudoku theory, but this simple fix worked for me. Initialize a `solved` attribute in the initializer:

```py
self.solved = False
```

When you know you're done, set it to `True`:

```py
print('Solved')
print(np.matrix(self.grid))
self.solved = True
```

And then nest the zeroing code in a conditional:

```py
if not self.solved:
    self.grid[y][x] = 0
```

Now that command will be skipped if your puzzle is already solved. There may be a more elegant way to implement the algorithm, but this fixes the functionality of your code.

(Note that as pointed out in Ian Wilson's answer, in your current code, `solver.grid` and the containing class's `self.grid` are one and the same, so the solver is actively changing the original grid supplied to it. This may or may not be what you intended.)

Answer (score 0):

Since python passes lists by reference, you are passing a reference to the old solver's grid.  You need to initialize your solver with a copy of the other grid like this:

```
import copy

class OtherClass():

    def start_solver(self):
        grid_copy = copy.deepcopy(self.get_grid())
        solver = SudokuSolver(grid_copy)
        #...
```

Because you have a list of lists, you have to use deep copy.  If it was just a single level list you could use `grid.copy()` or `grid[:]` to do a shallow copy.

It might be a good idea to move the copy operation into the constructor of the solver or into `get_grid()`.

[deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-how-do-i-clone-or-copy-it-to-prevent)

[pass by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value/430958)

Comment: Are you sure that's the issue? That just means that the solver's grid and the original grid are the same, so they should *both* change (which may or may not be fine in this case). But it appears that *neither* changes, and adding the deepcopy doesn't change the program output for me.

Comment: I think there are a lot of issues but you're right.  Reading their question again, they are expecting the opposite of what I thought was the problem.  They **want** the grid to be synced across all 3 classes but it is not synced.  Like your comment said, seems that we need to see there other 2 classes (all the code) to debug properly.  I probably jumped the gun.